# KivyMD with plyer Filechooser - How to get the path of a directory?

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser, kivymd

In `KivyMD` I use often the `plyer Filechooser` that looks to me really good for getting the path of a file, for a desktop application.

**PROBLEM**: **I cannot find a way to get the path of a directory**, I can get at the moment only the path of a file. Can you help me to get the path of a directory/folder?

Here my code:

```
from plyer import filechooser
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import filechooser



KV = """     

BoxLayout:
    id: box
    orientation: "vertical"                
    # size_hint: None, None
    # size: self.minimum_size 
    # pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}  
    spacing: dp(10)
    padding: dp(30)


    MDRoundFlatButton:
        id: openPathID
        text: "Get url"       
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}       
        on_release: app.file_manager_open()
        
    MDLabel:
        id: my_custom_label
        text: "URL"
        halign: 'center'      


"""

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_manager_open(self):
        raw_path = filechooser.open_file(title="Carica il file tempi in formato .xlsx",
                                                                  filters=[("Comma-separated Values", "*.xlsx")])
        self.root.ids.my_custom_label.text = raw_path[0]

DemoApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `choose_dir` instead of `open_file`

try: https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#plyer.facades.FileChooser.choose_dir